# strange behaviour of numpy masked array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking

I have troubles understanding the behaviour of numpy masked array.

Here is the snippet that puzzles me for two reasons:

```
arr = numpy.ma.array([(1,2),(3,4)],dtype=[("toto","int"),("titi","int")])
arr[0][0] = numpy.ma.masked
```

1. when doing this nothing happens, no mask is applied on the element `[0][0]`
2. changing the data to `[[1,2],[3,4]]` (instead of `[(1,2),(3,4)]`), I get the following error:
   `TypeError: expected a readable buffer object`

It seems that I misunderstood completely how to setup (and use) masked array.

Could you tell me what is wrong with this code ?

thanks

EDIT: without specifying the dtypes, it works like expected

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a masked array is to tell for any operation that some elements of the array are invalid to be used, i.e. masked.

For example, you have an array:

```
a = np.array([[2, 1000], [3, 1000]])
```

And you want to ignore any operations with the elements `>100`. You create a masked array like:

```
b = np.ma.array(a, mask=(a>100))
```

You can perform some operations in both arrays to see the differences:

```
a.sum()
# 2005
b.sum()
# 5

a.prod()
# 6000000
b.prod()
# 6
```

As you see, the masked items are ignored...

Comment: @PellegriniEric I've seen you haven't accepted any answer. Just to let you know, you can do it by clicking on the arrow at the left-hand side of the answer...